# If I have 10 virtual environment in python, will that download the same libraries 10 times?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Suppose I have created 10 different virtual environment for 10 different projects and 5 of them have same dependencies. So does this implies having the same library copy for 5 times or having the path to a globally installed package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the python and its default packages virtual environments does not share any other packages with each other. When you install a package It will first check for it in cache if found then install form there if not found then download to cache and install from there.

Comment: Yes. That means, the site packages will be present 10 times for 10 different virtual environments. correct?